# TabBar and NavBar disappears with segue. How can I pass data through NavController and/or keep NavBar and TabBar after segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue, xcode8

My Tabbed Bar and Navigation bar disappears whenever I use a Show Detail Segue to pass data through to another ViewController. I have managed to pass the relevant data in order to read which cell has been selected so I can insert a .txt file into a UITextField the the final ViewController. It's sort of like a dynamic textView. I would still like to be able to select different Tabs when I am in the article view (final vc). Is there any way to keep the NavBar and Tabbed View Bar in the final viewController after the segue, or is there a way to pass data through a Nav Controller. Or, sorry this will be the last one, do I use the prepare for segue and push the previous NavController (not too sure how to do this). Sorry I couldn't post more than 2 image links, hence the large amount of code. Thanks

Image 1: [Layout of the Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbA7A.png)

This is from rBVC.class (My Road Block Category Class File), where I have a TableView:

```
class rBVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var rBTableView: UITableView!

    var rBLabels = ["General Info", "Drunk Driving", "Arrest", "Searches"]

    var rBIcons = [UIImage(named: "generalInfo"), UIImage(named: "drunkDriving"), UIImage(named: "arrests"), UIImage(named: "searches")]

    var valueToPass: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return rBIcons.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

         let rBCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "rBCell", for: indexPath) as! rBCell
         rBCell.textLabel!.text = self.rBLabels[indexPath.row]
         rBCell.imageView!.image = self.rBIcons[indexPath.row]
         return rBCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
        //performSegue(withIdentifier: "rBASegue", sender: self)
        print(valueToPass)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "rBSegue"){
            /*let vcName = "rBTXT"
            let vC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vC!, animated: true)*/
            let indexPath = self.rBTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            let currentCell = self.rBTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! rBCell
            valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel?.text
            self.rBTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
            let viewController = segue.destination as! rBAV
            // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
            viewController.passedValue = valueToPass
            print("\(valueToPass)test")
        }
    }


}
```

Image 4: [This is where I have the problem of the disappearing bar's.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtRlN.png)

```
class rBAV: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var rBTV: UITextView!
    var passedValue: String?
    var rBArticle: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if passedValue == "General Info"{
            rBArticle = "rBGI"
        }

        if passedValue == "Drunk Driving"{
            rBArticle = "rBDD"
        }

        if passedValue == "Arrest"{
            rBArticle = "rBA"
        }

        if passedValue == "Searches"{
            rBArticle = "rBS"
        }

        // Save data to file
        let fileName = "Test"
        let DocumentDirURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        let fileURL = DocumentDirURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("txt")
        //print("FilePath: \(fileURL.path)")

         /*** Read from project txt file ***/

        // File location
        let fileURLProject = Bundle.main.path(forResource: rBArticle, ofType: "txt")
        // Read from the file
        var readStringProject = ""
        do {
            readStringProject = try String(contentsOfFile: fileURLProject!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed reading from URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
        rBTV.insertText(readStringProject)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: in your storyboard from which controller are you performing segue?

Comment: It is the Road Block View Controller (rBVC) that I'm performing it in, and it is going to the Road Block Article View Controller (final View Controller in storyboard). It appears after selecting the Road Block cell in the Categories View Controller.

Comment: To clarify: You have TabBarController... Center Tab is NavController... root VC of Nav is Categories table? And selecting a row shows Road Blocks Table? How are you getting to Road Blocks Table? Your image does not show a segue connection...

Comment: @DonMag Yes, you have the gist of the flow. I actually didn't end up fixing it. It gives me the a nil value for the value I'm trying to pass to the Article View... To get to road block I use the push method
`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated:true)
    }`

Comment: @TusharSharma So it performs a segue from the roadBlocks vc to the roadBlock Article vc (final vc).  I unfortunately did not solve this one just yet. DonMag and Tushar, I can't seem to pass the label to the article viewController (the final one in the storyboard, far right side) with a Show (Push) segue, but with Show Detail it works but doesn't display the top or bottom bars.

Comment: @Ryan de Kwaadsteniet your right most controller is not connected with tab bar or either navigation controller how you expect it to show.

Comment: Are you successfully pushing rVBC onto the NavController stack? So you display Road Blocks table based on the Categories row selected, and you can go back via the standard "< Back" button in the NavBar?

Comment: @TusharSharma It uses the navigationController?.pushViewController(). It does show when clicked.

Comment: @DonMag I do not understand the the first question. But, you are correct in saying I display the road Blocks Table according to the row selected and I do end up having the <Back button. Should I use a Show segue instead? Will it help connect the RoadBlock Article to the RoadBlock Table?

Comment: If it helps, I used my storyboard ID as an Identifier to show which vc the categories cell must push to

Comment: The road Block vc is also not the only vc that the Categories viewcontroller connects to. When I tried making multiple show segues between the categories table and the vc's, I could only select one vc for a segue.

Comment: Segues have their place, but can sometimes just confuse things... Since you are using TableViews and Navigation Controller, it *may* be easier for you to just delete any segues between table views and just use `.pushViewController()`

Comment: here is a full layout: [link](http://imgur.com/a/4BAGB)

Comment: So... you are laying out a separate TableViewController for *each* Category? Plus a separate "Dynamic Text View" controller for each of those? Are the 2nd-level table views so different that you need separate controllers? Or do they just show different data? Likewise, with the "final" dynamic-text controllers?

Comment: @DonMag It is a TableView within a ViewController, but yes, there is a separate one for each category, plus individual dynamic text controllers for each selectedCategory. They show different data for each 2nd level table (e.g. speeding fines has certain cells that would differ to road blocks). The final dynamic textviews also show different text files within the project file.

Comment: @RyandeKwaadsteniet - It still sounds like you're creating too many ViewControllers. You can create *one* VC that contains a TableView plus many different Custom Cells... then, based on which Category selected, use the corresponding Cell class. Same thing with your "final" view... One VC with a UITextView that gets dynamically filled from text files (or a database structure). Not only does that simplify your project, it makes it much, much easier to handle segues.

Comment: Thans @DonMag I think that will be the best option. There are a hell of a lot of custom cells so I'll rather have one class file with if statements. Thanks for all the help